# Load WMS into Map (Geotools)

Tags: wms, geotools, image

At the Moment I try to load a WMS-Map into a Java Geotools Project.
I followed every Step in the Userguide of Geotools.
(here the Link: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/wms/wms.html#getmaprequest)

At the end of the Guide it shows me how to Convert my GetMapResponse to a BufferedImage.

Until now I did not found a method, to get my Image into the MapContet.
The ImageLab Tutorial from Geotools imports an Image but as a File and not a BufferedImage.
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html

So Here the Code i created from the userguide

```
public void loadWMS() {
    URL url = null;
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "HIDDENURLHERE");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        view.setStatus("WMS-Url Fehlerhaft");
    }

    WebMapServer wms = null;
    try {
        wms = new WebMapServer(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        view.setStatus(
                "Fehler beim Verbinden Server evtl. Server offline");
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        view.setStatus("Server sendet eine ServiceException");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        view.setStatus(
                "Parsen der Server-Antwort nicht möglich oder nich valie Capabilities");
    }
    WMSCapabilities capabilities = wms.getCapabilities();

    GetMapRequest request = wms.createGetMapRequest();

    request.setFormat("image/png");
    request.setDimensions("600", "600");
    request.setTransparent(true);
    request.setSRS("EPSG:4326");
    request.setBBox("-180, -85.0511287798, 180, 85.011287798");
    for (Layer layer : WMSUtils.getNamedLayers(capabilities)) {
        request.addLayer(layer);
    }
    try {
        GetMapResponse response = wms.issueRequest(request);
        image = ImageIO.read(response.getInputStream());
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        view.setStatus("Server sendet eine ServiceException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        view.setStatus(
                "Fehler beim Verbinden Server evtl. Server offline");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `WMSLayer` object rather than requesting the image yourself. So something like:

```
for (Layer layer : WMSUtils.getNamedLayers(capabilities)) {
    map.add(new WMSLayer(wms, layer));
}
```

though I'd probably add some sort of selection functionality and error checking :-)

There is also an `addLayer(layer)` method that would allow you to build up a layered map in one go:

```
  public WMSLayer getWMSLayer() {
    String[] layers = this.layers.split(",");
    if (layers.length > 0) {
      WMSLayer ret = new WMSLayer(wms, layerList.get(layers[0]));

      for (int i = 1; i < layers.length; i++) {
        ret.addLayer(layerList.get(layers[i]));
      }
      return ret;
    }
    return null;
  }
```